# WebClient in .Net not releasing socket resources

Tags: .net, resources

I am having problems with some simple testing code that does bulk downloads from one of our restful services.  It appears that the low level socket is not being released by the call to Dispose.  Here is the basic code;

```
foreach(...)
{
  using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
  {
    string results = client.DownloadString("http://host/request");
    client.Dispose();
  }
}
```

This causes an exception after 255 loops.  I tried adding this line (via some suggestions form another stackoverflow post).

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 500;
```

Then I get an exception after 500 loops.  So, it seems to me the low level socket connection is not being released.

Has anyone else seen this issue?  Do you know a work around.

Thanks

Comment: The `client.Dispose()` is unnecessary, that's what the `using` is for.

Comment: Not an answer, but you don't need to call `Dispose` inside of a `using` block; the main point of the using block is that it ensure Dispose is automatically called.  Also, you could use just one `WebClient` instance and put the `foreach` inside of the `using` block.

Answer (score 1):

WebClient does not override the `Dispose` it inherits from `Component`.

There should not be a need to call the Dispose and I do not get the error you mentioned. Please mention the other stackoverflow post.

In fact, WebClient does not keep any state that would need dsiposing and is pretty stateless. Looking at the implementation in Reflector makes it obvious that it looks after the reasources in here (method `DownloadDataInternal` is called from `DownloadString`):

```
private byte[] DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, out WebRequest request)
{
    byte[] buffer2;
    if (Logging.On)
    {
        Logging.Enter(Logging.Web, this, "DownloadData", address);
    }
    request = null;
    try
    {
        request = this.m_WebRequest = this.GetWebRequest(this.GetUri(address));
        buffer2 = this.DownloadBits(request, null, null, null);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        if (((exception is ThreadAbortException) || (exception is StackOverflowException)) || (exception is OutOfMemoryException))
        {
            throw;
        }
        if (!(exception is WebException) && !(exception is SecurityException))
        {
            exception = new WebException(SR.GetString("net_webclient"), exception);
        }
        AbortRequest(request);
        throw exception;
    }
    catch
    {
        Exception exception2 = new WebException(SR.GetString("net_webclient"), new Exception(SR.GetString("net_nonClsCompliantException")));
        AbortRequest(request);
        throw exception2;
    }
    return buffer2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling GC.Collect to force the GC to run, seems that it might be the problem your having

Comment: This really should not make a difference for classes implementing `IDisposble`.

Comment: IIRC when you run under load there can be scenarios where the gc isn't able to run as it's supposed to, so the solution can be to call Collect on you own.

Comment: Component (base class of WebClient) already calls GC.Collect. If you use Reflector you can see that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead of `WebClient`.  In my experience, I usually have an easier time doing what I want with that API, though using it isn't quite as easy.  I believe you can control connections a lot easier with `HttpWebRequest`.