# Should one dispose of the WebResponse reference in WebException, if raised from WebClient?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, webclient, dispose, httpwebresponse

*Related question: [WebClient in .Net not releasing socket resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070503/webclient-in-net-not-releasing-socket-resources)*

While debugging a resource leak issue, I noticed that `System.Net.WebException` (a non-disposable type) contains a reference to `System.Net.WebResponse` (a disposable type).  I am wondering if I should dispose of this reference when explicitly handling a `WebResponse` as in the following snippet.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    WebException ex = Assert.Throws<WebException>(() => client.OpenRead(myUri));
    Assert.That(
        ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode,
        Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable));
}
```

The `WebException.WebResponse` reference is a copy of an existing reference in `WebClient`.  I thought that it would be disposed through `WebClient.Dispose` but this is not the case as `WebClient` does not override the protected `Component.Dispose(bool)` base method.  In fact, disassembly suggests that the `WebResponse` resource is never disposed of, but rather set to null when no longer needed.

```
public Stream OpenRead(Uri address)
{
    Stream stream2;

    // --- removed for brevity ---

    WebRequest request = null;
    this.ClearWebClientState();
    try
    {
        request = this.m_WebRequest = this.GetWebRequest(this.GetUri(address));
        Stream responseStream = (this.m_WebResponse = this.GetWebResponse(request)).GetResponseStream();

        // --- removed for brevity ---

        stream2 = responseStream;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

        // --- removed for brevity ---

        AbortRequest(request);
        throw exception;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.CompleteWebClientState();
    }
    return stream2;
}
```

... with `ClearWebClientState()` as follows:

```
private void ClearWebClientState()
{
    // --- removed for brevity ---

    this.m_WebResponse = null;
    this.m_WebRequest = null;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To be sure that WebResponse's resources are released you can explicitly call Close method.

Here's modified ClearWebClientState method:

```
private void ClearWebClientState()
{
    // --- removed for brevity ---
    if ( this.m_WebResponse != null )
        this.m_WebResponse.Close();
    this.m_WebResponse = null;

    this.m_WebRequest = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I realize that `Close()` will release the resource, however the example I gave is from the decompiled implementation of the `System.Web.WebClient` type and I don't have the luxury of changing that :)